# Java Stack display method, displays a '0' at top of Stack?

Tags: java

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I am creating a stack array. I am nearly done but when I display my Stack, there is an extra 0 at the top? To confuse me even more, when I call 'Peek' method, it displays the correct number at the top of the Stack and not the 0?? (nextfree is just an int set to 0 but maybe this where I am going wrong??)

```
public void display()
{
 if ( isEmpty() == true ) 
    {
        System.out.println("\nArray is Empty!\n");
        return;
    }  
 for (int i = nextfree; i >=0; i--) 
     System.out.println(array[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Where do you fill `array`?

Comment: What do you mean "nextfree is just an int set to 0"?  Are you saying it's set to 0 and never changed to anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't start your iteration at the `nextfree` position; I'm assuming that is the next available position and it's "beyond" the top of the stack.  The unused positions in an array of a primitive type are initialized to `0`, so that explains the extra `0` printed.

Starting iterating at `nextfree - 1`.

```
for (int i = nextfree - 1; i >=0 ; i--)
```

Comment: Argh, thank you! I am a noob but I still feel silly for not realising this. This fixed it! Once again, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`nextFree` points to your next free location I presume, so the `0` is from the free space.